# Compare values with Selenium and JXL

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jxl

The following code reads the spreadsheet cell values ​​with the JXL plugin and then compares these values with the values ​​on the page and chooses the matching value from the combo box.

The code I have works but it is case sensitive, the value must be identical.
I want to improve this code to search the combo box faster and select the closest value without being identical. Currently it runs through all values slowly.

```
String valDesejado = tipopromocao;
String valorComboBox = "";
Select verificaOpt = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("tipoDePromocaoPromocao")));

int tamanhoBox = verificaOpt.getOptions().size();
int variavelVerificadora1 = 0;
System.out.println("Tamanho: " + tamanhoBox);

for (int i = 0; i < tamanhoBox; i++)
{
    verificaOpt.selectByIndex(i);
    valorComboBox = verificaOpt.getFirstSelectedOption().getText().toString();

    if (valDesejado.equalsIgnoreCase(valorComboBox))
    {
        i = tamanhoBox;
        variavelVerificadora1 = 1;
    }

}
if (variavelVerificadora1 == 0)
{
    System.out.println("ALERTA: The Option + valDesejado + "  no comboBox \"tipoDePromocaoPromocao\" not found.");
}
```

Comment: Quick comment... you are missing a close quote here `"ALERTA: The Option + ...`. It should be `"ALERTA: The Option" + ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put some comments in the code that explains what I'm doing and makes corrections on a few things.

1. Instead of using an `int` and setting it to 0/1, use a `boolean` and set it to true/false.
2. This loop should be faster because I'm not selecting each option as I loop. You can examine the text of each option without selecting it... then once you find a match, select the match.
3. Use `break` to exit a loop instead of setting the counter to max value.

Give this code a try.

```
String valDesejado = tipopromocao;
boolean variavelVerificadora1 = false; // use boolean instead of int set to 0/1
Select verificaOpt = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("tipoDePromocaoPromocao")));
System.out.println("Tamanho: " + verificaOpt.getOptions().size());
// as this loops, the variable 'option' contains the current loops' OPTION element
// you don't need to select the option to get its text so this loop should be much faster
// it selects the OPTION once the correct one is found
for (WebElement option : verificaOpt.getOptions())
{
    if (valDesejado.equalsIgnoreCase(option.getText()))
    {
        verificaOpt.selectByVisibleText(option.getText()); // select the OPTION match
        variavelVerificadora1 = true; // set the boolean to true to indicate we found a match
        break; // exits the for loop
    }
}

if (!variavelVerificadora1) // this is the equivalent of variavelVerificadora1 == false, it's basically saying if not true
{
    System.out.println("ALERTA: The Option" + valDesejado + " no comboBox \"tipoDePromocaoPromocao\" not found.");
}
```